# Show the content of a subclass

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

I am new to Java and really like the challenge. Currently I'm trying to build a game that contains 3 classes (Warrior, Mage, Rouge) which the player can choose from. Therefore I created a constructor for the Basics (Health, Mana, Stamina) and subclasses for Warrior, Mage and Rouge.

I'd like to print the choice for the player, but unfortunately it won't work. Maybe someone can show me the right way.

This is the super class. Don't get confused by the german notations. :D

```
public class Klassen {

String Klasse;  
int Vitalitat; //Health
int Mana;
int Ausdauer; //Stamina

Klassen(String k, int v, int m, int a) {
    Klasse = k;
    Vitalitat = v;
    Mana = m;
    Ausdauer = a;
}
String getKlasse() {return Klasse;} //choice of classes
int getVit() {return Vitalitat;}
int getMana() {return Mana;}
int getAusdauer() {return Ausdauer;}

void setVit(int v) {Vitalitat =v;}
void setMana(int m) {Mana = m;}
void setAusdauer(int a) {Ausdauer = a;}
void setKlase(String k) {Klasse = k;}
void showBasic() {
    System.out.println("Vitalitaet: " + Vitalitat);
    System.out.println("Mana: " + Mana);
    System.out.println("Ausdauer " + Ausdauer);
}
```

Here an example of a subclass :

```
    public class Krieger extends Klassen {
    int Starke;

    Krieger(int v, int m, int a, int s) {

        super("Krieger", v, m, a);

        Starke = s;
    }

    int getStarke() {return Starke;}
    void setStarke(int s) {Starke = s;}

    void showStarke() {
        System.out.println("Starke: " + Starke);
    }
}
```

The next step is to create an array to hold all the three choices:

```
Klassen[] fillKlassen() {            //filling the array
        Klassen[] Auswahl = new Klassen[3];

            Auswahl[0] = new Krieger(0,0,0,0); //Warrior
            Auswahl[1] = new Magier(0,0,0,0);  //Mage
            Auswahl[2] = new Waldlaufer(0,0,0,0); //Rouge

            return Auswahl;                          
        }
```

The last step should be to create a method that prints the content of the arrays.
I guess something similar to:

```
class KlassenAuswahl {
Klassen[] fillKlassen() {
    Klassen[] Auswahl = new Klassen[3];

        Auswahl[0] = new Krieger(0,0,0,0); // Eclipse can't use that reference and wants me to change it to Klassen(int,int,int)
        Auswahl[1] = new Magier(0,0,0,0);
        Auswahl[2] = new Waldlaufer(0,0,0,0);

        return Auswahl;

    }
void showKlassen() {
    for(int i = 0; i < fillKlassen().length; i++) {
        System.out.println(fillKlassen()[i].getKlasse());

    }
}
```

The main goal is to implement this method in my main() Method but this won't work properly. Can someone help me out?

Edit: The main problem seems to be that I get a nullpointer.exception. This may a result of an empty array I guess? The next thing is that I can't implement the showAuswahl() in my main() perhaps because its inside in the constructor class. Therefore I need to create a new class outside of it. But outside of the constructor I can't use my subclasses...

Cheers
namelessshameless

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: It would be nice if you could translate the identifiers. Your English is clearly good enough to do so.

Comment: Sorry for that! I reworked the code :)

Comment: Could you specify on what line you get a null pointer exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. Needed to change my subclasses to static :)

Comment: So you defined all of them in one file? Usually every class is defined in its own file and that's the preferred method of how it should be done.

Comment: No worries! I defined a class that contains my costructors and another one for the whole show() stuff :)